# How to quickly enable/disable windows 10 (defender) antivirus?

Tags: windows-10, automation, shortcuts, control-panel, windows-defender

I would like to be able to quickly enable/disable windows defender antivirus.
If you type 'Defender' in the search box (aka Cortana) you will see see a 'Windows Defender settings' item. How can I get a desktop shortcut to that program?

Comment: Alternatively, I am also interested in the WinAPI command or the registry they that will enable/disable Defender. I could build a small tool then.

Comment: Hmm there's no `ms-settings` shortcut for Defender.. Probably for security reasons(?).  if you need to disable/reenable Defender in a hurry, why not just toggle the service with `SC` or alike?

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

1. Create a shortcut on the desktop.
2. Open the shortcut properties and assign these values:

   - Target:

     ```
     "%WinDir%\Explorer.exe" "%LocalAppData%\Packages\windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Indexed\Settings\en-US\AAA_SettingsPageWindowsDefender.settingcontent-ms"
     ```

     (Ensure to change "**en-US**" to your locale region code)
   - Working directory:

     ```
     %WinDir%
     ```
3. Have fun!.

---

Here is a demo I made in my locale settings:

[image]

Note: Tested on Windows 10 build **10240** and **10565**.

---

> Alternatively, I am also interested in the WinAPI command or the
>   registry they that will enable/disable Defender.

Theorically the **WDEnable** Win32 function could toggle the state of Windows Defender:

- **[WDEnable function - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762466%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)**

However, seems complicated because security reasons as pointed out in this question:

- **[How to enable Windows Defender in C# - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30616109/how-to-enable-windows-defender-in-c-sharp)**

Comment: This really neat hack no longer works, at least not for me. The folder LocalState exists but is empty.  Windows 10 v1909. 
%LocalAppData%\Packages\windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState\Indexed\Settings\en-US\AAA_SettingsPageWindowsDefender.settingcontent-ms

Answer (score -1):

Open control panel, Right click on Windows Defender, select create shortcut.
 It will pop a message saying it can not be created here would you like it on the desktop, select Yes.

Comment: This will not create a link to the settings window. Only to the Defender main window.